# How to implement coroutine within for loop in c

Tags: c, coroutine

Here is part code:

```
void a()
{
    printf("entering a\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if(setjmp(a_buf) == 0) {
            printf("A step %d\n", i);
            b();
        } else {
            longjmp(b_buf, 1);
        }
    }
    printf("returning from a\n");
}

void b()
{
    printf("entering b\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(setjmp(b_buf) == 0) {
            printf("B step %d\n", i);
            a();
        } else {
            longjmp(a_buf, 1);
        }
    }
    printf("returning from b\n");
}
```

I have two processes `a` & `b`. How to make them works as coroutine.
Wish them doing `A Step 0` then `B Step 0` then back to `A Step 1`... until both finished. But looks like counter `i` never changed.

Comment: If you want to serialize execution of 2 processes, why do you use 2 processes at all?

Comment: @Gerhardh I having the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383520/why-should-i-use-coroutine-in-c-c

Comment: That's the same weird `setjmp`-massacre. Then put it this way: If you want serial execution of single steps why would you want to organize them in such a set of functions? Just call the stepts within one function. Or maybe maintain a static variable in the second function that holds information about which step to execute next. Or are you searching for a problem that might match your semi-solution?

Comment: @Gerhardh I am studying about how to make the _correct_ coroutine implementation in C. Then wiki and google told me the solution need using `setjmp`. So I am searching the right way lead me to the real 'coroutine'. don't care it's good or not, just wondering how to make it works.

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve? Using coroutines just for the sake of using coroutines sounds a bit strange. The comment to your linked question is very true.

Comment: Also your other question is based on a (incorrect) answer to a question looking for some usecase for `setjmp`. It doesn't make much sense to insist on using it unless it really solves your problem. Which you don't tell us.

Comment: @Gerhardh That incorrect answer is the beginning of all of these question I asked...I am just trying to know what's coroutine in C.

Comment: I'm having the exactly same question as you. But people created this evil `setjmp` and tell me it's way of the coroutine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171611/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-jiu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve using your code here is not defined.

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§7.13.2.1p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.13.2.1p2)

> The `longjmp` function restores the environment saved by the most recent invocation of the `setjmp` macro in the same invocation of the program with the corresponding jmp_buf argument. If there has been no such invocation, or if the invocation was from another thread of execution, **or if the function containing the invocation of the `setjmp` macro has terminated execution** in the interim, or if the invocation of the `setjmp` macro was within the scope of an identifier with variably modified type and execution has left that scope in the interim, the behavior is undefined.
>
> <sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

Regarding what counts as terminated execution:

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§note248](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#note248)

> For example, by executing a return statement or because another `longjmp` call has caused a transfer to a `setjmp` invocation in a function earlier in the set of nested calls.

So, say you call `a()` first, and it calls `b()` after setting the `a_buf`. Now `b()` sets the `b_buf` and jumps back to `a`. At this point `b`'s execution has terminated and if you jump back to `b_buf`, the behavior is undefined.

One possible solution for your problem could be to define functions `a_step()` and `b_step()` which perform just a single step of `a()` and `b()` respectively. Then call them alternatively in a loop.

Comment: I understand _At this point b's execution has terminated_. So in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685406/practical-usage-of-setjmp-and-longjmp-in-c the example of the first answer is wrong?

Comment: @Jiu yes the example is completely wrong. Read the comments for that answer. It is possible for very primitive functions and not supported by the standard. It just works because of some artifacts of how *some* compilers work.

Answer (score 4):

The `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` functions can only be used to exit from a nested subroutine, as a sort of "throw/catch". They cannot be used to reenter a subroutine that has already exited, either through a `return` or through a `longjmp()`. In short, they cannot be used this way.

The only well-defined way to implement coroutines in C is [as a state machine](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html). There is no way to implement coroutines as normal subroutines, as this is incompatible with the C stack.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the "s_task" coroutine, which may be the answer for you --

https://github.com/xhawk18/s_task

features --

1. written in pure c and asm, without c++ required
2. asm code from boost context, which is robust and effective
3. add keywords **await** and **async**
4. supports various platforms, such as windows, linux (arm,x86,mips), stm32, stm8
5. have integrated with libuv for network programming
6. "event" and "mutex" object for communication between coroutings

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved elegantly with coroutines from the [STC library](https://github.com/stclib/STC), using Duff's device.

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/354fhKKMx

```
#include <stc/coroutine.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct a { int i; int cco_state; };
struct b { int i; int cco_state; };

int coro_a(struct a* g)
{
    cco_routine (g) {
        printf("entering a\n");
        for (g->i = 0; g->i < 3; g->i++) {
            printf("A step %d\n", g->i);
            cco_yield();
        }
        cco_final:
        printf("returning from a\n");
    }
    return 0; // done
}

int coro_b(struct b* g)
{
    cco_routine (g) {
        printf("entering b\n");
        for (g->i = 0; g->i < 5; g->i++) {
            printf("B step %d\n", g->i);
            cco_yield();
        }
        cco_final:
        printf("returning from b\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct a a = {0};
    struct b b = {0};
    
    while (coro_a(&a) | coro_b(&b)) {}
}
```