# setjmp / longjmp does not jump where I think it should

Tags: c, setjmp

I would like to understand how setjmp / longjmp works, so I created an example program, where routineA prints even, routineB prints odd numbers and they jump to each other with longjmp:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define COUNTER_BEGIN 0
#define COUNTER_END   6

void routineA( jmp_buf* pEnvA, jmp_buf* pEnvB );
void routineB( jmp_buf* pEnvA, jmp_buf* pEnvB );

int main() {
    const char message[] = "main      [ &envA=0x^%016lx &envB=0x^%016lx ]  -- %s\n";
    jmp_buf envA;
    jmp_buf envB;

    fprintf( stdout, message, &envA, &envB,
             "Started; Before calling routineA" );
    routineA( &envA, &envB );
    fprintf( stdout, message, &envA, &envB,
             "After routineA returned; Exiting" );

    return 0;
}

/* Prints even numbers from COUNTER_BEGIN to COUNTER_END */
void routineA( jmp_buf* pEnvA, jmp_buf* pEnvB ) {
    const char* message = "routineA: [ i=%d, sjr=%d ]  -- %s\n";
    static int i;
    static int sjr;
    static jmp_buf *s_pEnvA;
    static jmp_buf *s_pEnvB;

    s_pEnvA = pEnvA;
    s_pEnvB = pEnvB;
    fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "After saving statics; Before starting the for loop" );
    for( i = COUNTER_BEGIN; i < COUNTER_END; i++ ) {
        if( i % 2 == COUNTER_BEGIN + 0 ) {
            fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "Inside for and if; Before setjmp" );
            sjr = setjmp( *s_pEnvA );           /* Added */
            if( sjr == 0 ) {                    /* Added */
            /* if( ( sjr = setjmp( *s_pEnvA ) ) == 0 ) { */
                fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "Got to this line directly - go to routineB somehow" );
                if( i == 0 ) {
                    fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "This is the first iteration - call routineB as function" );
                    routineB( s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB );
                } else {
                    fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "This is not the first iteration - longjmp to routineB" );
                    longjmp( *s_pEnvB, 12 );
                }
            } else {
                fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineB) - continue" );
                ; /* Just continue */
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "After the for loop, Before leaving the function" );
}

/* Prints odd numbers from COUNTER_BEGIN to COUNTER_END */
void routineB( jmp_buf* pEnvA, jmp_buf* pEnvB ) {
    const char* message = "routineB: [ i=%d, sjr=%d ]  -- %s\n";
    static int i;
    static int sjr;
    static jmp_buf *s_pEnvA;
    static jmp_buf *s_pEnvB;

    s_pEnvA = pEnvA;
    s_pEnvB = pEnvB;
    fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "After saving statics; Before starting the for loop" );
    for( i = COUNTER_BEGIN; i < COUNTER_END; i++ ) {
        if( i % 2 == 1 ) {
            fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "Inside for and if; Before setjmp" );
            sjr = setjmp( *s_pEnvB );           /* Added */
            if( sjr == 0 ) {                    /* Added */
            /* if( ( sjr = setjmp( *s_pEnvB ) ) == 0 ) { */
                fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "Got to this line directly - longjmp to routineA" );
                longjmp( *s_pEnvA, 21 );
            } else {
                fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineA) - continue" );
                ; /* Just continue */
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf( stdout, message, i, sjr, "After the for loop, Before leaving the function" );
}
```

I compiled it with gcc and received the following output (line numbers inserted for later reference):

```
01 main      [ &envA=0x^00007ffce81b0280 &envB=0x^00007ffce81b01b0 ]  -- Started; Before calling routineA
02 routineA: [ i=0, sjr=0 ]  -- After saving statics; Before starting the for loop
03 routineA: [ i=0, sjr=0 ]  -- Inside for and if; Before setjmp
04 routineA: [ i=0, sjr=0 ]  -- Got to this line directly - go to routineB somehow
05 routineA: [ i=0, sjr=0 ]  -- This is the first iteration - call routineB as function
06 routineB: [ i=0, sjr=0 ]  -- After saving statics; Before starting the for loop
07 routineB: [ i=1, sjr=0 ]  -- Inside for and if; Before setjmp
08 routineB: [ i=1, sjr=0 ]  -- Got to this line directly - longjmp to routineA
09 routineA: [ i=0, sjr=21 ]  -- Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineB) - continue
10 routineA: [ i=2, sjr=21 ]  -- Inside for and if; Before setjmp
11 routineA: [ i=2, sjr=0 ]  -- Got to this line directly - go to routineB somehow
12 routineA: [ i=2, sjr=0 ]  -- This is not the first iteration - longjmp to routineB
13 routineA: [ i=2, sjr=21 ]  -- Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineB) - continue
14 routineA: [ i=4, sjr=21 ]  -- Inside for and if; Before setjmp
15 routineA: [ i=4, sjr=0 ]  -- Got to this line directly - go to routineB somehow
16 routineA: [ i=4, sjr=0 ]  -- This is not the first iteration - longjmp to routineB
17 routineA: [ i=4, sjr=21 ]  -- Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineB) - continue
18 routineA: [ i=6, sjr=21 ]  -- After the for loop, Before leaving the function
19 main      [ &envA=0x^00007ffce81b0280 &envB=0x^00007ffce81b01b0 ]  -- After routineA returned; Exiting
```

The output is OK until line 12: `This is not the first iteration - longjmp to routineB`, however, after this it should go to routineB, and print `Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineA) - continue` but it stays in routineA, and says `Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineB) - continue`.

Is there an error in my code or do I misunderstand something about setjmp / longjmp?

**Update**

Revised the code according to Eric Postpischil's answer's first part: I think now it suits the last bullet point, as an assignment statement is an expression statement. I received the same result (except for different pointer values).

Alright, I replaced `sjr = setjmp( *s_pEnvA );` (and the corresponding part of routineB) with

```
sjr = -1;
switch( setjmp( *s_pEnvA ) ) {
case  0: sjr =  0; break;
case  1: sjr =  1; break;
case 12: sjr = 12; break;
case 21: sjr = 21; break;
default: sjr = -2; break;
}
```

I think this is completely in line with the bullet point "the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement".

The result is still the same.

**Final update**

Eric and Nate are right, this is undefined behavior. But since I was wondering why the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685406/practical-usage-of-setjmp-and-longjmp-in-c/14685524) works, I transformed my code gradually to that one, and watched at which point it breaks. I ended up with this:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined( SORTOFWORKS )
#define CHECKPOINTFORMAT "routineX:\n  -- %s\n\n"
#elif defined( DOESNOTWORK )
#define CHECKPOINTFORMAT message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr
#else
#error Version (SORTOFWORKS or DOESNOTWORK) is not defined
#endif

#define STRINGIFY( x ) STRINGIFY_IMPLEMENTATION( x )
#define                STRINGIFY_IMPLEMENTATION( x ) #x

#define COUNTER_BEGIN 0
#define COUNTER_END   6

void routineA( jmp_buf* pEnvA, jmp_buf* pEnvB );
void routineB( jmp_buf* pEnvA, jmp_buf* pEnvB );

int main() {
    const char message[] = "main      [ &envA=0x^%016lx &envB=0x^%016lx ]\n  -- %s\n\n";
    jmp_buf envA;
    jmp_buf envB;

    fprintf( stdout, message, &envA, &envB,
             "Started; Before calling routineA the first time" );
    routineA( &envA, &envB );
    fprintf( stdout, message, &envA, &envB,
             "Before calling routineA the second time" );
    routineA( &envA, &envB );
    fprintf( stdout, message, &envA, &envB,
             "Exiting" );

    return 0;
}

/* Prints even numbers from COUNTER_BEGIN to COUNTER_END */
void routineA( jmp_buf* pEnvA, jmp_buf* pEnvB ) {
    const char* const message = "routineA: [ pEnvA=0x^%016lx, pEnvB=0x^%016lx, s_pEnvA=0x^%016lx, s_pEnvB=0x^%016lx, i=%d, sjr=%d ]\n"
                                "  -- %s\n\n";
    static int i;
    static jmp_buf *s_pEnvA;
    static jmp_buf *s_pEnvB;
    static int sjr;

    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "Called; Before saving statics" );
    s_pEnvA = pEnvA;
    s_pEnvB = pEnvB;
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "After saving statics; Before starting the counting" );

    fprintf( stdout, CHECKPOINTFORMAT,
             "Checkpoint A0 at line " STRINGIFY( __LINE__ ) );

    i = COUNTER_BEGIN;
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "Part of counting; Before setjmp" );
    sjr = -1;
    switch( setjmp( *s_pEnvA ) ) {
    case  0: sjr =  0; break;
    case  1: sjr =  1; break;
    case 12: sjr = 12; break;
    case 21: sjr = 21; break;
    default: sjr = -2; break;
    }
    if( sjr == 0 ) {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line directly - This is the first iteration - call routineB as function" );
        routineB( s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB );
    } else {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineB) - continue" );
        ; /* Just continue */
    }

    fprintf( stdout, CHECKPOINTFORMAT,
             "Checkpoint A1 at line " STRINGIFY( __LINE__ ) );

    i += 2;
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "Part of counting; Before setjmp" );
    sjr = -1;
    switch( setjmp( *s_pEnvA ) ) {
    case  0: sjr =  0; break;
    case  1: sjr =  1; break;
    case 12: sjr = 12; break;
    case 21: sjr = 21; break;
    default: sjr = -2; break;
    }
    if( sjr == 0 ) {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line directly - This is not the first iteration - longjmp to routineB" );
        longjmp( *s_pEnvB, 12 );
    } else {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineB) - continue" );
        ; /* Just continue */
    }

    fprintf( stdout, CHECKPOINTFORMAT,
             "Checkpoint A2 at line " STRINGIFY( __LINE__ ) );

    i += 2;
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "Part of counting; Before setjmp" );
    sjr = -1;
    switch( setjmp( *s_pEnvA ) ) {
    case  0: sjr =  0; break;
    case  1: sjr =  1; break;
    case 12: sjr = 12; break;
    case 21: sjr = 21; break;
    default: sjr = -2; break;
    }
    if( sjr == 0 ) {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line directly - This is not the first iteration - longjmp to routineB" );
        longjmp( *s_pEnvB, 12 );
    } else {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineB) - continue" );
        ; /* Just continue */
    }

    fprintf( stdout, CHECKPOINTFORMAT,
             "Checkpoint A3 at line " STRINGIFY( __LINE__ ) );

    /* Should be able to do this but it causes segfault: longjmp( *s_pEnvB, 12 ); */

    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "After the counting, Before leaving the function" );
}

/* Prints odd numbers from COUNTER_BEGIN to COUNTER_END */
void routineB( jmp_buf* pEnvA, jmp_buf* pEnvB ) {
    const char* const message = "routineB: [ pEnvA=0x^%016lx, pEnvB=0x^%016lx, s_pEnvA=0x^%016lx, s_pEnvB=0x^%016lx, i=%d, sjr=%d ]\n"
                                "  -- %s\n\n";
    static int i;
    static jmp_buf *s_pEnvA;
    static jmp_buf *s_pEnvB;
    static int sjr;

    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "Called; Before saving statics" );
    s_pEnvA = pEnvA;
    s_pEnvB = pEnvB;
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "After saving statics; Before starting the for loop" );

    fprintf( stdout, CHECKPOINTFORMAT,
             "Checkpoint B0 at line " STRINGIFY( __LINE__ ) );

    i = 1 + COUNTER_BEGIN;
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "Part of counting; Before setjmp" );
    sjr = -1;
    switch( setjmp( *s_pEnvB ) ) {
    case  0: sjr =  0; break;
    case  1: sjr =  1; break;
    case 12: sjr = 12; break;
    case 21: sjr = 21; break;
    default: sjr = -2; break;
    }
    if( sjr == 0 ) {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line directly - longjmp to routineA" );
        longjmp( *s_pEnvA, 21 );
    } else {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineA) - continue" );
        ; /* Just continue */
    }
    
    fprintf( stdout, CHECKPOINTFORMAT,
             "Checkpoint B1 at line " STRINGIFY( __LINE__ ) ); /* SORTOFWORKS: printed, DOESNOTWORK: missing */

    i += 2;
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "Part of counting; Before setjmp" );
    sjr = -1;
    switch( setjmp( *s_pEnvB ) ) {
    case  0: sjr =  0; break;
    case  1: sjr =  1; break;
    case 12: sjr = 12; break;
    case 21: sjr = 21; break;
    default: sjr = -2; break;
    }
    if( sjr == 0 ) {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line directly - longjmp to routineA" );
        longjmp( *s_pEnvA, 21 );
    } else {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineA) - continue" );
        ; /* Just continue */
    }
    
    fprintf( stdout, CHECKPOINTFORMAT,
             "Checkpoint B2 at line " STRINGIFY( __LINE__ ) ); /* SORTOFWORKS: printed, DOESNOTWORK: missing */

    i += 2;
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "Part of counting; Before setjmp" );
    sjr = -1;
    switch( setjmp( *s_pEnvB ) ) {
    case  0: sjr =  0; break;
    case  1: sjr =  1; break;
    case 12: sjr = 12; break;
    case 21: sjr = 21; break;
    default: sjr = -2; break;
    }
    if( sjr == 0 ) {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line directly - longjmp to routineA" );
        longjmp( *s_pEnvA, 21 );
    } else {
        fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
                 "Got to this line via longjmp (in this program it must be from routineA) - continue" );
        ; /* Just continue */
    }
    
    fprintf( stdout, message, pEnvA, pEnvB, s_pEnvA, s_pEnvB, i, sjr,
             "After the for loop, Before leaving the function" );
}
```

If you compile the above with `gcc -DSORTOFWORKS -o ./jump_sortofworks ./jump.c`, then it prints the lines marked with the comment `/* SORTOFWORKS: printed, DOESNOTWORK: missing */` but if you compile it with `gcc -DDOESNOTWORK -o ./jump_doesnotwork ./jump.c`, then it doesn't (Compiler: GNU C11 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) version 6.3.0 20170516 (x86_64-linux-gnu)).

I think the fact that such a small change (different string format to print) breaks it, clearly demonstrates that setjmp / longjmp cannot be used for this purpose.

Comment: Do not print pointers with `%lx`. Convert them to `void *` and print them with `%p`.

Comment: I think Eric kind of buried the lede.  Your code is fundamentally not what `longjmp` does.  It's not for arbitrarily jumping around between functions; it is for jumping up the call stack only, essentially forcing several layers of functions to return at once.  You might use it if a function far down the stack encounters an error that can only be handled much further up, e.g. by aborting a computation and continuing the program's main loop.  If you're familiar with `throw/catch` in C++ or other languages, think of `longjmp/setjmp` as a primitive version of that.

Comment: An assignment expression with a semicolon is an expression statement, but the `setjmp` invocation in it is not the entire expression statement as the C standard calls for. It is just a subexpression within the statement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Does this mean, I cannot save setjmp's return value to a variable? Why should I supply a value to longjmp if I can't use it?

Comment: @z32a7ul: You can use a `setjmp` in the controlling expression of a `switch` and pick out the individual values with `case` labels.

Comment: That's what I just did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the behavior of your calls to `setjmp` is not defined by the C standard because they violate the constraints in C 2018 7.13.1.1 4 and 5:

> An invocation of the `setjmp` macro shall appear only in one of the following contexts:
>
> — the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement;
>
> — one operand of a relational or equality operator with the other operand an integer constant expression, with the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement;
>
> — the operand of a unary `!` operator with the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; or
>
> — the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to `void`).
>
> If the invocation appears in any other context, the behavior is undefined.

For example, in `if( ( sjr = setjmp( *s_pEnvA ) ) == 0 )`, the `setjmp` invocation is not the entire controlling expression, it is not an operand of a relational or equality operator (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, or `!=`),  it is not the operand of `!`, and it is not the entire expression of an expression statement.

Second, `longjmp` can only jump up the call stack, to functions that are still executing. Once a call to a function stops executing (as when it returns), you cannot jump back into that call. Your code saves the context in `routineB`, then jumps to `routineA` (which ends execution of `routineB`), then attempts to jump to the saved context. But C 2018 7.13.2.1 2, about `longjmp` says:

> … if the function containing the invocation of the `setjmp` macro has terminated execution in the interim,… the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I don't see why the second part is a problem. At output line 12 both functions (routineA and routineB) are still running, and the for loop has multiple iterations to do, right?

Comment: @z32a7ul: When `routineB` jumps to `routineA` with `longjmp`, it ends the execution of `routineB`.

Comment: There is another question on SO, and as I see it does something similar to my code: it jumps between two functions (although without loops). What makes the difference? Or is that one wrong, as well?

Comment: @ z32a7ul: Which question?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter too early. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685406/practical-usage-of-setjmp-and-longjmp-in-c/14685524

Comment: @z32a7ul: The C standard says what the C standard says. That other question contains code by some person. That person and their code are not the C standard. The code might have “worked” for them due to some particular characteristics of their C implementation and how they used it. In addition to the text of the standard I quoted, note 253, referred to from that text, says “For example, by executing a `return` statement or because another `longjmp` call has caused a transfer to a `setjmp` invocation in a function earlier in the set of nested calls.” So this case is specifically covered.