# Cycle main loop from inner subroutine, in Fortran

Tags: error-handling, fortran

I have a large Fortran code that computes the evolution of a system through time. The code is subdivided in modules, each of them tackle a precise physical process.
The last module compiled, i.e. the module that depends on all others, is the one that executes the main loop through time. At a given time step, a bunch of equations are solved and if we are happy with the quality of the solutions, time is increased by a certain amount `dt`, otherwise, `dt` is divided by two and the loop starts over. It looks, schematically, like this:

```
subroutine sub_main(args)
    use mod1, only: sub11, sub12, ...
    use mod2, only: sub21, sub22, ...
    ...

    main_loop: do
        ! solve equations:
        call sub11( ... )
        call sub22( ... )
        ...

        if (problem) then
            dt = dt / 2.0
            cycle main_loop
        else
            t = t + dt

    enddo main_loop

end subroutine sub_main
```

Usually, convergence issues, or other problem are detected only one level below this subroutine, for instance directly in `sub11` or `sub22`. In this case, catching what kind of issue occurred through a flag is easy. In addition, `sub11` or `sub22` are only called in the scope of `main_loop`.

However, sometimes problems occur in much deeper subroutines. For instance, in `sub_abc` called in `sub_def`, called, in `sub_ghi`, called in `sub_21`. In addition, this `sub_abc`, where the problem occur, is also sometimes called outside of the `main_loop`. In such case,  we do not want to decrease the time step if a problem occur.

My question is then: is there a way to either (1) decrease the time step and cycle the `main_loop` from the inner subroutine `sub_abc`, or (2) to exit `sub_abc`, `sub_def`, `sub_ghi` and `sub_21` automatically, and go back in subroutine `sub_main` where `main_loop` is defined, and then decrease `dt` ? (or any other solution to my problem).
I recall that `sub_main` is part of a module that depends on `mod1`, `mod2`, etc.

Thank you for your ideas ! (I am opened to any standard of Fortran >= 90)

Comment: No. As presented you will have to `Return` all the way up the call tree

Comment: You can set a flag in a generally-accessible module - perhaps one dedicated to holding flags - and examine that within the main loop.

Comment: Or you can give your subroutines another output argument for status.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with that solution (which works, though) is that I need to check the value of the flag after each call of the routine, for all the routines called. I was wondering if a way exists to automatically go back to main_loop.

Comment: No, I am pleased to say Fortran has no equivalent of C's [longjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685406/practical-usage-of-setjmp-and-longjmp-in-c)  (However one thing the language is really missing IMO is proper exception handling). I'd have an error flag associated with each routine and test on return, if you can avoid global state do so.

Comment: If you could jump back directly from a very deep subroutine to main then you would be able to bypass the normal returns from an intermediate subroutine and that could lead to memory leak from any allocated arrays that weren't de-allocated properly. Checking a single status variable or global flag isn't an expensive operation, even if it means a fraction more code.