# Why gcc does some optimizations with -O0

Tags: c, linux, gcc, optimization

I compiled the following code with gcc 4.8.4 and with -O0 flag:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static jmp_buf env;

static void
doJump(int nvar, int rvar, int vvar)
{
    printf("Inside doJump(): nvar=%d rvar=%d vvar=%d\n", nvar, rvar, vvar);
    longjmp(env, 1);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nvar;
    register int rvar;          
    volatile int vvar;         

    nvar = 111;
    rvar = 222;
    vvar = 333;

    if (setjmp(env) == 0) {     
        nvar = 777;
        rvar = 888;
        vvar = 999;
        doJump(nvar, rvar, vvar);
    } else {                    
        printf("After longjmp(): nvar=%d rvar=%d vvar=%d\n", nvar, rvar, vvar);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It produced the following output:

```
Inside doJump(): nvar=777 rvar=888 vvar=999
After longjmp(): nvar=777 rvar=222 vvar=999
```

My expectation was that rvar will be 888 in the second row as all optimizations are disabled.

When I remove 'register' from definition of 'rvar' or when I add 'volatile' in front of 'register', it outputs 888.

So it seems that gcc still performs some optimizations inspite of -O0 flag.

Is there a way to disable absolutely all optimizations in gcc?

Comment: What's your definition of an "optimization"? (I am not being funny; this is a serious question.)

Comment: In the particular case it puts 'rvar' in a register. Isn't that an optimization?

Comment: It's hard to call the compiler putting something in register an optimization when you told it to put it in a register.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1393474/1287251), `setjmp` works by saving the registers to the stack (and then `longjmp` just restores those registers from the stack). If that's the case, then it makes sense, as `rvar` would be saved at `setjmp` and its later modifications would not. In this case, I don't think you're observing any optimizations here at all.

Comment: register keyword just "advises" the compiler to put it in a register.

Comment: Hrant, what optimizations are you thinking are taking place? I don't think the compiler is doing any optimizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C11 standard says for `longjmp()`:

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine<sup>249)</sup>
>   have state, as of the time the `longjmp` function was called, except that the values of
>   objects of automatic storage duration that are local to the function containing the
>   invocation of the corresponding `setjmp` macro that do not have volatile-qualified type
>   and have been changed between the `setjmp` invocation and `longjmp` call are
>   indeterminate.
>
> <sup>249)</sup> This includes, but is not limited to, the floating-point status flags and the state of open files.

You are running into indeterminate values...standard conforming behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

if your posted code is compiled with all warnings enabled, as it should have been, then three warnings are output:

```
warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]

warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
```

the above can be fixed with replacing:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
```

with

```
int main( void )
```

and the important one:

```
warning: variable 'ravr' might be clobbered by 'longjmp' or 'vfork' [-Wclobbered]
```

Which answers you question and shows that compiling has to be done with all warnings enabled.  for gcc, at a minimum use:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```